# Using python to change directory information with one-liner code

Tags: python

I have this code to change directory information in python. I'd like to change '/a/b/c' into '/x/b/c'.

```
import os

x = "/a/b/c"
y = x.split(os.sep)
y[1] = 'x'
os.sep.join(y)
```

Now I just want to know if python can make it one-liner. I can't simply use `os.sep.join(x.split(os.sep)[1] = 'x')` as it causes an syntax error. What might be other options in python?

Comment: Why do you have to do it in one line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
os.sep.join('x' if idx == 1 else element
            for idx, element in enumerate(x.split(os.sep)))
```

result:

```
'/x/b/c'
```

Explanation: `enumerate` pairs each element of `x.split(os.sep)` with its index. `'x' if idx == 1 else element` replaces the element with 'x' if it is the 1th element, and leaves it intact otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

This is likely rather inefficient:

```
y = os.sep.join([x.split(os.sep)[0]] + ['x'] + x.split(os.sep)[2:])
```

Comment: If you don't want to call `split` twice, you could use a lambda function, like this: `(lambda elements: os.sep.join([elements[0]] + ['x'] + elements[2:]))(x.split(os.sep))`

Comment: @Kevin That's pretty clever!  I like it.

Comment: Yes, it's very useful for one-liners, since assignment is impossible. Whenever you ask yourself, "how do I calculate a value once and use it multiple times later?", consider using `lambda`.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work too:

```
y = os.sep + 'x'+ x[2:]
```

Comment: It does for the example case, but would fail in a number of situations, such as `x` not starting with `os.sep`, the top-level directory contained more than one character, if `os.sep` itself wasn't a single character... this is why using `os.path` functions is so important.